# Converting images locally when using the GAE Images Java API

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, tiff

I am having an issue with calling applyTransform() from ImagesService when running locally. When deployed to GAE the image is transformed fine, locally I get a 500 error with this 
exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to read image
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(ImagesServiceImpl.java:397)
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.applyTransform(ImagesServiceImpl.java:88)
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.applyTransform(ImagesServiceImpl.java:65)
...
```

I am converting from tiff to png and I have tried adding various libraries as dependencies but to no avail (jai-imageio, tom gibara's, javaVP8). I continue to get this warning:

```
Nov 26, 2012 6:30:37 PM com.google.appengine.api.images.dev.LocalImagesService init
WARNING: No image reader found for format "tif". An ImageIO plugin must be installed to use this format with the DevAppServer.
```

Any suggestions on how I may be able to make this work outside of the GAE environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview?hl=en#Development_Server) might be helpful.

"The development server uses your local machine to perform the capabilities of the Images service."

Installation instruction [here](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html).

Comment: That page is really all I've found on the topic and unfortunately it is not at all helpful. It just states that a plugin is required locally which is what i describe above as trying.

Comment: installation instruction at http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html

Comment: That was it. Thanks! I installed jai_imageio-1_1-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe